# SQL Server: Is it good/best practices to create an index for a nvarchar column with length of 4000?

Tags: sql-server, indexing, nvarchar

I have a column `staff_id` in my master staff table, the datatype is `nvarchar` with 4000 max character. It is used to store the id for staff in the company, e.g 00002244. If I want to make this column as a foreign key in other table (`staff_id`, not the primary key id), is it good to create the index for this column, even if the datatype is `nvarchar(4000)`? Or is it better if I don't make the index?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you really need an `nvarchar(4000)` column to hold 8 character ID values? The use of `nvarchar(4000)` makes this seem like a pre-SQL 2005 database that already has some design issues.

Comment: `nvarchar(4000)` seems excessive for this column. Index key columns must be a maximum of 900 bytes anyway.

Comment: I see, well, the database design that I received is like that, so I want to ask is it good to create index for that column. I'll just talk to the one who designed the database about the column length then. Many thanks for the response everyone !!

Comment: [Maximum Capacity specifications for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/maximum-capacity-specifications-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15): "Bytes per index key: 900 bytes for a clustered index. 1,700 for a nonclustered index.". So if you're going to index it, you'd want to reduce the size anyway since any oversize values would cause the insert/update to be rolled back.

Comment: Oversized fields can also cause severe performance problems because memory grants balloon to unreasonable sizes. If every query that retrieves a lot of rows starts reserving memory in anticipation of reading this "large" field, the number of queries that can happen concurrently drops. This is especially noticeable if the field appears a lot in intermediate structures, like hash tables or spools for joins, so doing this for a key field is doubleplusungood.

Comment: _I'll just talk to the one who designed the database_ This should become a habit for you and your coworkers. Discuss things, learn from each other, find your strengths and weaknesses.

Comment: 100% agree with everything said by everyone so far. Additionally, even if you did need to store the numbers as text, `nvarchar` is just gratuitous. You're using two bytes for every digit, whereas varchar would use one byte.